# Excel: Display the unique results of match query in multiple columns rather then just one

Tags: excel, unique

I am trying to find a way to display the results of the following equation in multiple columns rather in just in a single row.

=INDEX($C$3:$C$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$2:G2,$C$3:$C$10)+($B$3:$B$10<>$E$3),0),)

The data set is listed below:

[image]

Instead of the list of A B D in cells G3,G4,G5 , I would like them to be listed in G2, H2, I2.

Any words of advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula in G3 and fill right.

```
=INDEX($C3:$C10, MATCH(0, IF($B3:$B10=$E3, COUNTIF($F3:F3, $C3:$C10)), 0))
```

[image]

Comment: fwiw, i prefer this cse formula method for unique conditional values in steadof the one you provided. It can easily be modified to produce values in rows.

Comment: I can not argue with results ! Thanks again